# jquery css height, what is wrong?

Tags: jquery, css, dom, height

I'm trying to manipulate the height on some elements using jquery, i't does not work. The error lays in this line, what am I doing wrong?

```
$(body, html, ".page", ".off-canvas-wrap", ".inner-wrap").css("height", 100+"px");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)**](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/), pass comma separated selectors

```
$("body, html, .page, .off-canvas-wrap, .inner-wrap").css("height", 100+"px");
```

Additionally use [**.height()**](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

```
$("body, html, .page, .off-canvas-wrap, .inner-wrap").height(100);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code has lot of syntax errors, the selectors in the `$(selector)` have to all be within a single string. And you can use `.height(value)` instead of using `.css('height',value)`

Try:

```
$("body, html, .page, .off-canvas-wrap, .inner-wrap").height(100);
```

Comment: You better fix your own typos :)

Comment: You missed the double-quotes at the end of selector. It's corrected now. Good answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Syntax  is wrong :

```
$( "body, html,.page, .off-canvas-wrap, .inner-wrap").css("height", 100+"px");
```

Comment: answer is similar to Saptal's answer

Comment: +1 for `quick wit` and `answer` and `being bff`!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding an explanation to what others have answered already :

```
$("body, html, .page, .off-canvas-wrap, .inner-wrap").css("height", 100+"px");
```

**Explanation :**

Jquery selectors are also just like css,so assuming you have a div which needs multiple classes you would do :

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3">\* <--all classes in one single string quote*\
```

and not

```
<div class="class1", "class2", "class3">
```

Similar is the pattern for this question in selectors of jquery....hope it clears your idea!! :)

```
$("body, html, .page, .off-canvas-wrap, .inner-wrap").css("height", 100+"px");
```

and not

```
$(body, html, ".page", ".off-canvas-wrap", ".inner-wrap").css("height", 100+"px");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use correct [selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) and combine it with [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) function of jquery. You could even separate the wanted elements to variable for easier reuse:

```
var myElements = $('body, html, .page, .off-canvas-wrap, .inner-wrap');
myElements.height(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

you must separate your selectors whith a comma inside the parentheses
like this basic exemple

```
$('.class,.class2').css({
    height : '100px'
});
```

or

```
$('.class,.class2,.class3').css('height',80);
```

(why do you inclue de body and html tags?)